# Can't read properties of null for addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on recipe page. I need to read checkboxes. Every time I press submit error appears (Can't read properties of null reading addEventListener).

```js
function submitrecipe() {
  breakfast = document.getElementById('breakfast');
  lunch = document.getElementById('lunch');
  dinner = document.getElementById('dinner');
  submit = document.getElementById('submit');
  try {
    submit.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input=[name="typeofmeal"]:checked');
      let values = [];
      checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
      });
    });
    console.log(values);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. You do not need a try/catch if you add the event listener after the DOM has rendered. Just wrap in `window.addEVentListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { /* code here */ });`

Comment: 2. Do not have a function that can be called more than once add an eventListener

Comment: 3. Do not add a click event listener to a submit button. Instead listen for the form submit event and use `event.preventDefault();` to not submit the form

Comment: This kind of question is very well suited for an LLM like chatgpt - I recommend you try it!